# undefined reference error to several function

Tags: c, data-structures

While running this c program to implement linked list operations I am getting undefined reference error to several functions like undefined reference to  create_list , undefined reference to display, etc. I have also read about this error in this site but I am not getting exact meaning of these error. I have no clue about this errors, So please help me to understand these errors.

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < stdlib.h >
struct node {
  int info;
  struct node * link;
};
struct node * create_list(struct node * start);
void display(struct node * start);
void count(struct node * start);
void search(struct node * start, int data);
struct node * addatbeg(struct node * start, int data);
struct node * addatend(struct node * start, int data);
struct node * addafter(struct node * start, int data, int item);
struct node * addbefore(struct node * start, int data, int item);
struct node * addatpos(struct node * start, int data, int pos);
struct node * del(struct node * start, int data);
struct node * reverse(struct node * start);
main() {
  struct node * start = NULL;
  int choice, data, item, pos;
  while (1) {
    printf("1.Create list\n");
    printf("2.Display\n");
    printf("3.Count\n");
    printf("4.Search\n");
    printf("5.Add to empty list/Add at beginning\n");
    printf("6.Add at end\n");
    printf("7.Ad after node\n");
    printf("8.Add before node\n");
    printf("9.Add at position\n");
    printf("10.Delete\n");
    printf("11.Reverse\n");
    printf("12.quit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice:\n");
    scanf("%d", & choice);
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
      start = create_list(start);
      break;
    case 2:
      display(start);
      break;
    case 3:
      count(start);
      break;
    case 4:
      printf("Enter the elements to be searched:");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      search(start, data);
      break;
    case 5:
      printf("Enter the element to be inserted");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      start = addatbeg(start, data);
      break;
    case 6:
      printf("Enter the element to be inserted: ");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      start = addatend(start, data);
      break;
    case 7:
      printf("Enter thee element to be inserted");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      printf("Enter the element after which to insert");
      scanf("%d", & item);
      start = addafter(start, data, item);
      break;
    case 8:
      printf("Enter the element to be inserted: ");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      printf("Enter the element before which to insert");
      scanf("%d", & pos);
      start = addbefore(start, data, item);
      break;
    case 9:
      printf("Enter the element to be inserted");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      printf("Enter the position at which to insert");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      break;
    case 10:
      printf("Enter the elements to be deleted");
      scanf("%d", & data);
      start = del(start, data);
      break;
    case 11:
      start = reverse(start);
      break;
    case 12:
      exit(1);
    default:
      printf("Wrong choice\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, *formatting*. Indentation might not be needed for the compiler, but for people reading your code it's kind of important. Secondly, if you get build errors of any kind, please copy (as text, full and complete including any possible informational notes) the messages and paste them (without modifications) into the body of your question.

Comment: Also, you don't declare [the `main` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) correctly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's not too difficult to run through https://codebeautify.org/c-formatter-beautifier or similar, especially for new users :-) Takes about as much time to write a comment

Comment: Please tell us which lines are generating the errors. Are these runtime or compiler errors?

Answer (score 2):

Your program has *declared* the functions, but it hasn't *defined* them. All you've done is told it how to call `create_list` but not how it should implement that function.

Is there another file that goes with this one? Chances are, these functions are defined in another file, and you need to tell the compiler to use that file's compiled output to define these functions.